# Contain image size with parent <div>

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, object-fit

I´ve been trying to keep my images next to each other on the same line, and just crop them to a smaller size if needed. Why doesn't `object-fit` work ?

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="inner"><img src="images/image1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="inner"><img src="images/image2.jpg"></div>
  <div class="inner"><img src="images/image3.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.inner{
   width: 333px;
   height: 300px;
}

.inner img{
   object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: so i want the image to stay the same ( nothing getting cut of) but i just want the size to become the same as the parent DIV .inner. 

I´m new to coding so if stuff does not make sense please tell me.

Comment: Try `height: 100%` in `.inner img`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should set the `width` and `height` on the `img` in order to use it with `object-fit`. And it looks like `object-fit: cover;` might be what you're after.

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Full snippet:

```css
.gallery {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
  /*or flex: 1; */
  /*or width: 33.333333%; */
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="inner"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300"></div>
  <div class="inner"><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600"></div>
  <div class="inner"><img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this works with Firefox and Edge. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ConAntonakos - on my end it works fine on Firefox, Edge, and Chrome.